# Why does a '.' work in chown?

Tags: history, gnu, chown, coreutils

Why does GNU `chown user.group` work? The docs say nothing of the syntax being supported. Is there a juicy story behind it?

Comment: Same question [here](http://serverfault.com/q/194295)

Comment: great example of a question that should have been migrated here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`info chown` is clear on that:

```
Some older scripts may still use `.' in place of the `:' separator.
POSIX 1003.1-2001 (*note Standards conformance::) does not require
support for that, but for backward compatibility GNU `chown' supports
`.' so long as no ambiguity results. New scripts should avoid the use
of `.' because it is not portable, and because it has undesirable
results if the entire OWNER`.'GROUP happens to identify a user whose
name contains `.'.
```

In case of `GNU` programs it's often worth checking not only `man` but also `info` pages because *GNU folks abhor man pages* (from `man tar`).

Comment: Important historical context: when `chown` first gained the ability to do user and group in a single command (4.3BSD is the earliest such example I can find), people didn't do crazy things like put dots in their usernames. Dots, dashes, capital letters, more than 8 characters long... all unthinkable. Also the colon is the one character that's safe from future growth of the set of allowable usernames, because it's the separator in `/etc/passwd`